`ldconfig` not found on any `apt-get install`, `upgrade`, etc commands. `PATH` seems to be set correctly for su
I'm getting this error when I attempt to install anything with apt-get install:
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Rather concerning is that I do not find ldconfig within those paths listed (/usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin)!
I do remember upgrading libc6 a few weeks ago in an attempt to get something else working, i.e. Agda unicode files, which probably landed me in this mess in the first place.
Does anyone know of ways to save my Ubuntu installation at this point?
